# How to pass Jinja2 variable to javascript

Tags: jinja2

1. How to pass Jinja format variable to javascript
   Ex: **{{a.Value}}**
   How to pass the a.value to javascript ?
   Getting this variable from py file.

Answer (score 0):

You just pass through render_template as normal:

```
var = 'data’
return render_template('index.html', var=var)
```